# CSS style over riding Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, templates

I'm learning HTML and CSS on my own by resources available online.

I took this template using Bootstrap and made it my own using my content. I have the problem that when I make changes to style on CSS, these changes doesn't take effect on the page when refreshing.

It looks like CSS doesn't over ride some code in the Bootstrap. Any suggestion or correction into making style effective?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
      <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

<title>Home Cleaning Services in the SF Bay Area</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sparkling Cleaning SF</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Estimates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <img class="Cleaning-Logo" src="img/SparklingCleanLogo.jpg">
        <h1>Cleaning Services in the SF Bay Area</h1>
        <p>With a growing economy and a vibrant style of life, the SF Bay area has become home for professionals, families, artists and everyone who wants to be part of this great region.
        Due to this, it’s very difficult to devote time to clean or organize our space where we live or work. 
        Sometimes we say to ourselves we will get to clean up our stubborn room or bathroom, but we don’t get to do it because you don’t have the time or the least thing you would like to do in your free time is to get to the obstinate place.</p>

    </div>
```

```
<section>

</section>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: maybe you have `style.css` in the same folder as `bootstrap.css`? in that case you must do `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` like you do for boostrap, not `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: I don't understand. I have Documents/Sparkling Cleaning Project/... with folders of css, fonts, IMG, js, and Index.thml. In the css folder I have bootstrap.css file, boostrap.mini.css, and style.css, which this is the one I make all the style changes.

Comment: ok, then you must write `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`, notice the `css/` part

Comment: It totally worked! Thanks. Could you explain me why it worked?

Comment: for the same reason why you used `href="css/bootstrap.css"` (at the `<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->` part), you should also use `href="css/style.css"` (at the `<!-- Custom styles for this template -->`), and the reason is: the files are in the `css` subfolder, so you must specify the name of this subfolder

Comment: easy file-pathing is the reason. if you put your files in a folder and you want to point at them, you have to get the right pathing from your root folder. in that case, like wil93 already said, you have to use href="css/style.css". href is the pathing to your file.

Comment: and you'll need to change the jscript at bottom as well. to <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

Comment: Thank you all for your responses!